# Consider a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ s.t $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 4321|x-y|$. Choose the correct option:

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

This is a  MCQ question, consider a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ s.t $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 4321|x-y|$. Choose the correct option:

1) $f$ is always diffrentiable.

2) there exist atleast one such $f$ continuous but non-differentiable at exactly $2018$ points and $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=2018$

3) there exist atleast one such $f$ continuous s.t $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=\infty$

4) It is not possible to find a sequence of reals $\{x_n\}$ diverging to infinity s.t $\lim_{x_n \to \infty}\frac{f(x_n)}{|x_n|}\leq 10000$.

Now for sure option 1) is not true any $f(x)=1 $  forall $x>1$ and $f(x)=0$ forall $x\leq1$ will give us the counter but what are logics for the rest.

Comment: Your counterexample for (1) doesn't work: take an $x > 1$ and a $y < 1$ and you can make them as close as you like and therefore $4321|x-y|$ as small as you like, but $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is always 1. In other words, that function doesn't satisfy the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe  that with $y = 0$ have $$|f(x)| \le |f(x) - f(0)| + |f(0)| \le 4321|x| + |f(0)|$$ so that
$$ \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|} \le 4321 + \frac{|f(0)|}{|x|} $$
whenever $x \not= 0$.

This rules out (3) and (4) right away. The simple example $f(x) = |x|$ rules out (1).

So (2) is the only option left.

Comment: Does this not rule out (3), not (2)?

Comment: I have corrected a typo, please check(approve or modify) my edit. Moreover, can you give the reason why (2) is true!!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: If possible please upvote the question.